# Como mostrar uma mensagem após uma ação de enviar?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

Estou tentando fazer com que o aplicativo Android mostre uma mensagem de "email enviado com sucesso" após um e-mail, que está atrelado a ação do botão enviar, ser enviado corretamente. Tentei mostrar um Toast, porém ele mostra antes de o e-mail ser enviado.

Segue o código

```
void enviar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        RadioButton rdbgrupo1 = FindViewById<RadioButton>(rdgconquiste.CheckedRadioButtonId);
        RadioButton rdbgrupo2 = FindViewById<RadioButton>(rdgcrie.CheckedRadioButtonId);
        RadioButton rdbgrupo3 = FindViewById<RadioButton>(rdgviva.CheckedRadioButtonId);
        RadioButton rdbgrupo4 = FindViewById<RadioButton>(rdgentregue.CheckedRadioButtonId);
        int RadioGroupIsChecked(RadioGroup radioGroup)
        {
            //-1 means empty selection
            return radioGroup.CheckedRadioButtonId;
        }

        //When user doesn't check a radio button, show a Toast
        if (RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgconquiste) == -1 || RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgcrie) == -1 || RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgviva) == -1 || RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgentregue) == -1)
        {
            string excecao = "Ao menos um botão de cada campo deve ser selecionado e o comentário deve ser preenchido";
            Toast.MakeText(this, excecao, ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }
        else
        {
            String emailescolhido = spinner.SelectedItem.ToString();
            String campocomentario = comentário.Text;

            var email = new Intent(Android.Content.Intent.ActionSend);
            //send to
            email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraEmail,
            new string[] { "" + emailescolhido });
            //cc to
            email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraCc,
            new string[] { "" });
            //subject
            email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraSubject, "SABIA QUE VOCÊ FOI RECONHECIDO?");
            //content
            email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraText,
            "Você foi reconhecido pelo(s) valor(es) de: " + rdbgrupo1.Text + " , " + rdbgrupo2.Text + " , " + rdbgrupo3.Text + " e " + rdbgrupo4.Text + "                                                                      " + " " + campocomentario);
            email.SetType("message/rfc822");
            StartActivity(email);

        }

        string enviado = "Email enviado com sucesso";
        RunOnUiThread(() => Toast.MakeText(ApplicationContext, enviado, ToastLength.Long).Show());
    }
}
```

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/81278/how-to-handle-the-result-of-startactivityforresult-in-forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pois bem, acredito que seu erro esteja na lógica, em seu "IF" você tem uma tratativa de exceção, e em seu "ELSE" seria onde você faz de fato o envio do e-mail, ou seja, o Toast deveria estar no final do ELSE, assim:

```
//When user doesn't check a radio button, show a Toast
if (RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgconquiste) == -1 || RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgcrie) == -1 || RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgviva) == -1 || RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgentregue) == -1)
{
    string excecao = "Ao menos um botão de cada campo deve ser selecionado e o comentário deve ser preenchido";
    Toast.MakeText(this, excecao, ToastLength.Long).Show();
}
else
{
    String emailescolhido = spinner.SelectedItem.ToString();
    String campocomentario = comentário.Text;

    var email = new Intent(Android.Content.Intent.ActionSend);
    //send to
    email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraEmail,
    new string[] { "" + emailescolhido });
    //cc to
    email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraCc,
    new string[] { "" });
    //subject
    email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraSubject, "SABIA QUE VOCÊ FOI RECONHECIDO?");
    //content
    email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraText,
    "Você foi reconhecido pelo(s) valor(es) de: " + rdbgrupo1.Text + " , " + rdbgrupo2.Text + " , " + rdbgrupo3.Text + " e " + rdbgrupo4.Text + "                                                                      " + " " + campocomentario);
    email.SetType("message/rfc822");
    StartActivity(email);

    string enviado = "Email enviado com sucesso";
    RunOnUiThread(() => Toast.MakeText(ApplicationContext, enviado, ToastLength.Long).Show()); 
}
```

Outro ponto, mas que serviria apenas para organização de código seria modificar um pouco este teu método para ficar mais claro colocando a toda a parte inicial e também o IF dentro de um método de validações, caso seja válido você executa o código dentro do else. Mas isso é só uma ideia.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Obrigado, sua dica funcionou!
Uma dúvida, você sabe como faço para separar o email em parágrafos?
Por exemplo: eu queria que os valores do RadioGroup fossem enviados em um parágrafo e o comentário do campo EditText fosse em um parágrafo abaixo do primeiro

Comment: Se fizer a separação na mão mesmo, não da? e essa biblioteca do email Intent(Android.Content.Intent.ActionSend) não tem algo sobre isso? desculpe mas eu não sei dizer.